# Accessing jsonb object in postgress throws error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

I have a table called "junaid", which has a column "connections" which is of type "jsonb".

```
create table junaid (
   connection jsonb
}
```

The value in the "connections" column is array of objects.

```
conections = [{"name":"abc", "age":123},{"name":"xyz", "age":222}]
```

I have a stored procedure to access these values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE   
myconnection jsonb;
i jsonb;
BEGIN
    select connections into myconnection from junaid;


    FOR i IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(myconnection)
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'output from space %', i->>’name’;
    END LOOP;
    return 0;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    return 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run the stored proc, I get this error:

> column "’name’" does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using wrong quote characters. Instead of backticks or forward ticks or whatever, you should be using the *single-quote character* for the keyname too, as you seem to be using for the format string. I.e. it should be `i->>'name'`.

P.S. SO syntax highlighting shows that something fishy is going on...